# [UICachedDeviceWhiteColor pointSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c424a5c0'

Tags: ios

The application is crashing when i launch the Application. (Xcode 9, iOS 11)

Error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor
>   pointSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c0452870'

Thanks

Comment: Can you add an exception breakpoint and share with us the code please?

Comment: Give us more information so we can help you

Comment: sorry guys!! This is my first question.. No problem. Now i found that issue and resolved it. check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Actually the project i was working on was developed by unfamiliar developer. They set the placeholder color keypath as `placeHolderColor` to `UITextField`.

[image]

I just removed that and fixed with `_placeholderLabel.textColor`
[image]

Now i didn't get any crash while launching the Application

Thanks